# Angular 2 selected option on condition

Tags: html, select, angular

I have a select:

```
  <select id="position">
    <option *ngFor='#contactType of contactTypes' [attr.value]='contactType.contactTypeId'>
      {{contactType.description}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

I would like to have a selected option on condition: '**contactType.contactTypeId == number**' without using **ngModel**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
 <select id="position">
    <option *ngFor='#contactType of contactTypes'
      [attr.value]='contactType.contactTypeId' 
      [attr.selected]="contactType.contactTypeId == number ? true : null">
      {{contactType.description}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

To get the `selected` attribute removed you need to return `null` (`false` results in `selected="false"`).